# document.lastModified and date

Tags: javascript, date, time

Im trying to make something like, time after last change.

```
    <script language="javascript">
        var x = new Date(Date.parse(document.lastModified));
        document.write(x - document.lastModified);
    </script>
```

I've got this code but Im getting NaN instead of time. What's wrong?

Comment: what `document.lastModified` contains? and what is `x`?

Comment: You might want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse

Answer (score 0):

Try to think about solving the problem by evaluating the code yourself.
Here's what this evaluates to in a 'frame by frame' view:

1

```
     var x = new Date(Date.parse(document.lastModified));
    document.write(x - document.lastModified);
```

2

```
     var x = new Date(Date.parse("11/29/2013 14:37:21"));
    document.write(x - document.lastModified);
```

3

```
    var x = new Date(1385753841000);
    document.write(x - document.lastModified);
```

4

```
    var x = "Fri Nov 29 2013 14:37:21 GMT-0500 (EST)";
    document.write(x - document.lastModified);
```

5

```
    document.write("Fri Nov 29 2013 14:37:21 GMT-0500 (EST)" - "11/29/2013 14:37:21");
```

6

```
    document.write(NaN);
```

And you get a NaN because string minus string === `NaN`.

Frame 3 where you parse the date returns a UNIX Epoch timestamp (number of seconds since 1970 midnight GMT). You can subtract two epochs to get a difference of seconds.

Comment: Ok, once I have diffrence of seconds, what should i do?